# Postgres ODBC Connection String error from PowerShell

Tags: postgresql, powershell, connection

The ODBC connection is ok from the ODBC Data Source Administrator (see below image) but failed from PowerShell.

I got the below exception.
Exception setting "ConnectionString": "Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification start
ing at index 0." from

what is wrong with the connection string?

Here is the code

```
$Query = "select distinct name, friendly_name from _users order by name"
$DWServer = "MyServer"
$DWUser = "readonly"    
$DWPwd = "readonly" 
$DWDatabase = "workgroup"
$Port = 8060

#$ConnectionString = "Driver={PostgreSQL35W}:Server=$DWServer;Port=$Port;Database=$DWDatabase;Uid=$DWUser;Pwd=$DWPwd;"
$ConnectionString = "Driver={PostgreSQL UNICODE(x64)}:Server=$DWServer;Port=$Port;Database=$DWDatabase;Uid=$DWUser;Pwd=$DWPwd;"
try
{
    # 1. Connect to DB
    
$Conn = New-Object System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnection; 
    $Conn.ConnectionString = $ConnectionString
    $Conn.Open()
    $Command = $Conn.CreateCommand()
    $Command.CommandText  = $Query
    $Result = $Command.ExecuteReader()
    
    $DocCount = 0
        
    while ($Result.Read())
    {
        try
        {   
            $ADId = $Result.GetValue(0) 
            $FullName = $Result.GetValue(1)
            
            $DocCount = $DocCount + 1
            $LicenseName = $ADId  +" " + $FullName  
            
            Write-Output " ********** $DocCount ---  $LicenseName"
            
        } # end of try
        catch
        {
            $ErrorMessage = $_.Exception.Message
            $FailedItem = $_.Exception.ItemName
            
            Write-Output  "*** Exception while catch for $LicenseName ----- $ErrorMessage from $FailedItem"
        } # end of catch
      
    }  # end of  while
}  # end of outer try
catch
{
    $ErrorMessage = $_.Exception.Message
    $FailedItem = $_.Exception.ItemName
    
    Write-Output "*** Exception  Outer Catch for $LicenseName ----- $ErrorMessage from $FailedItem"
} # end of outer try
finally
{
    $Conn.close()
}
```

[image]

Comment: Looks like the colon (`:`) in your connection string should actually be a semicolon (`;`).

Comment: Thanks so much to point it out. It works now